# Open Declaration not working for java.util.HashSet in Eclipse 4.2.2

Tags: java, eclipse

You know how in the Eclipse Java editor you can do Open Declaration (F3) on a classname and it will navigate to the source for the class?  And if you attach the JDK source it will do this for classes in the JDK?  That's working fine for me in Juno (Eclipse version 4.2.2, build: M20130204-1200), except for java.util.HashSet.

Oddly, Open Declaration works for java.util.Hashtable and other classes in java.util, but for HashSet, it says "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file HashSet.class."  I checked the attached source (from Oracle/Java) and of course it does.

Has anyone seen this or know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever eclipse starts bugging out on me I clean my projects.  If that doesn't work I restart eclipse.  If that fails I restart my computer. I know these are very basic tips but they're tried and true.

Comment: By "check[ing] the attached source" do you mean checking that the source zip file contained in the JDK directory *on your computer* contains the file? This zip file is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\src.zip` on my computer if that's any help. I don't know about Eclipse, but NetBeans tells me the location of the file when hovering over the filename of a standard API file.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.  I also tried unzipping src.zip but had the same result: Eclipse can find all classes except java.util.HashSet.  And yes, I tried restarting Eclipse and even rebooted (good ol' Windows). Thanks.